# In a SQL Server view, get the "AS" info for the columns in the view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

So I have a view that has lots of "AS" stuff defined for different columns, e.g., some view columns simply map to one column in one physical table, some are defined by functions etc:

```
SELECT
   dbo.LoanDataTable.F123 AS LoanOfficer, 
   dbo.udf_GetChannelTypeValueWithLoanOfficer(dbo.LoanDataTable.F123) AS ChannelType
```

In our application I want to be able to display on a web page the mapping of the view columns to their "AS" definitions, in a grid with two columns like so:

```
LoanOfficer     dbo.LoanDataTable.F123
ChannelType     dbo.udf_GetChannelTypeValueWithLoanOfficer(dbo.LoanDataTable.F123)
```

I have researched on stackoverflow:

[Is there a way to retrieve the view definition from a SQL Server using plain ADO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765323/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-the-view-definition-from-a-sql-server-using-plain-ado)

and

[Suggestions on storing view meta in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032306/suggestions-on-storing-view-meta-in-sql-server-2008)

All the first one does is retrieve the full text of the view definition, and no one ever answered the second one.

If I retrieve the full text of the view definition, such as seen at the top of this post, then I still need to somehow parse the text to extract the "AS" components.  So my question is: is there a way to easily extract this information from SQL Server 2008 R2 and above, or if not, has someone already written some view-definition-parser code that will do this?

Comment: Here's a link to a question about getting view information from yesterday:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19687112/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-columns-in-a-table-or-view/19688199#19688199. Anything you get back will require some sort of parsing tho.

Comment: Not that such view-definition-parser code would be rocket science, but hey, if someone else has already done it, it would just be nice to save the time :)

Comment: Thanks Andrew, the info in that post is very helpful in general sense (especially the sp_columns system stored procedure, which is pretty handy), but still doesn't get to the "AS" info in the view definition :)

Comment: It wouldn't be rocket science, but it would be pretty close to a functioning lexical analyzer.  Consider what you would have to be able to evaluate to show TableName.ColumnName - Aliases, Explicit Joins, Implicit Joins, Subqueries, With, As, Without the As, [] for column names.. I could go on and on.  Not quite rocket science, but pretty complicated nevertheless.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I don't think it would be that hard to get the info that I am after (a simple key-value list). A high-level description of the general algorithm would be:  1) extract what comes after 'SELECT' and before the other valid DDL keywords that can come after the column definitions; 2) split the extracted column definitions by comma; 2) take the splitted chunks and each one has one thing that comes before the ' AS ', and one thing after it; 3) there is the 2 sets of values (note that I don't need to drill down any further into anything that is before the ' AS ').

Comment: No, there is no way to *easily* extract this information.

Comment: If someone has already spent what would likely be a couple of hours of coding, it seems reasonable to me to check to see if they have.  But that's just me :)  Also note that the actual code could be in either T-SQL, or in C#.NET, either would be fine for my purposes.

Comment: I'm going to leave this open until later today, then if no one responds that they have a solution already, I'll go ahead and whip out the code.  Also, if I do that, I will try to do it in T-SQL first (even though it would be easier/quicker in C#.NET) because then the resultant code would be able to be used by others regardless of their application programming HLL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you the actual DDL, if that's the first part of what you're looking for:

```
SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION (OBJECT_ID('yourSchema.yourViewGoesHere')) AS ObjectDefinition;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the most concise way I've seen to get the full definition as a starting point.